# How to update store state in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a component in React (with Redux) that has the requirements to:

1. Retreive data from an API endpoint.
2. Display that data, with one field being editable.
3. If the editable field *is* edited, it has to update the rest of the fields and send them to a different endpoint.

I'm having trouble grasping how exactly I should implement the editing using the Redux metodology.

Here is a simplified component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.props.dispatch(getDataFromEndpoint());
  }
  editField(e) {
    this.props.dispatch(editFieldAction(e.target.value));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.data.editableField} onChange={this.editField} />
        {
          this.props.data.uneditable.map(x => {
            return (
              <span>{x}</span>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
      );
  }
}

const mapProps = state => {
  const { data } = state.endpointData;
  return { data };
}

export default connect(mapProps)(MyComponent);
```

Note that I've written this component as an example, it might have errors, but you should get the point. Whenever `this.editField` is called, it should update every value in `this.props.data.uneditable`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a sense these questions all boil down to: How do I wire up my component(s) to read from (and write to) Redux state. This is essentially the purpose of redux-react's connect function (which you have in the bottom of your example). You use the first parameter, mapStateToProps, to be able to read from state. You use the second parameter (that you don't have yet) - mapDispatchToProps - to provide the means to write to it. Dispatching an action is how you update Redux state.

You *can* simply use this.props.dispatch, but it is more idiomatic to use mapDispatchToProps, which simply provides an object where each property is a function which calls dispatch with the appropriate action creator. You might accept as a parameter for example the data which you are looking to update your store with.

What ends up happening is in your component when you want to update the state (say from an input), you use the methods you wired up with mapDispatchToProps to dispatch an action with the relevant data (the updated input value), and then write a reducer which responds to the action and updates the relevant part of your store. Redux will then trigger a re-render in your component and it will pull the updated data from the store.

Async actions are handled a bit differently of course (which is what your API calls will be), because they typically have several changes to state being spread out over time. Usually something like:

- Start the API request. (Dispatch an action to..) Set a flag somewhere in your state indicating the API request is 'in transit'.
- Receive the response. (Dispatch again to..) Set a flag somewhere saying the request is finished, and if it was successful, store your response data somewhere. If it was an error, store the error (or just the fact there was an error).

I would recommend redux-thunk for this purpose, since at least for me it is the easiest to understand and work with out of all the various libraries and methods to handle async with redux. Instead of dispatching an object which contains the data describing the action, you instead dispatch a function, which means you can write any kind of logic you would like, allowing you to dispatch several times for example. This makes it easy to do the steps outlined above.. simply have a function which calls your API, and in the callback (or `.then()` method) you dispatch an action with the result.

Comment: So in other words if you wanted to update both local and remote state (ie update your local store AND make an API call with the same data to send to the server), this would be a good case for a thunk, because you could both dispatch an action which would update your local store and also send off the API request from within the same thunk.

Comment: Great explination. Whay kind of functions should I pass into mapDispatchToProps, and what parameters should it take, so I can update the storebstate?

Comment: Well this just depends on how you want to model your data in your store. Let's say for example you have a 'person' object with the fields 'name' and 'address'. You could either have two different actions (say, `updateName` and `updateAddress`), in which case you would probably just pass in a single string that you grabbed from your text input's onChange event (for the new input value).. OR you could have a single action (perhaps `updatePerson`) which would include the updated person object, in which case you dispatch an action with the entire person object; even if only 1 field changed

Comment: Say you went with the latter because you wanted to re-use the same action for your entire object's multiple fields, you could have your component's onChange method for each text input grab the entire person object from this.props (for example) and then simply replace the one field that changed, and then call this.props.updatePerson (which was mapped by mapDispatchToProps). and then in mapDispatchToProps you have an object with field updatePerson which looks something like: (person) => {dispatch(updatePerson(person));}

Comment: Awesome, I'll try it out. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I would love to see examples of how to read and write to the redux store